# JavaScript Polymer change variable value depending on global variable

Tags: javascript, polymer

I don't know how to explain myself or if it is even possible, so here it goes an example:

I want the "hidden" variable to take the value of the global variable depending on the "tag" value.

```
var sport = false;
var music = true;

Polymer({
    publish: {
        tag: "sport",
        hidden: xxxxxx
    }
});
```

So if tag is "sport", I want "hidden" to be "false"; and if tag is "music", I want "hidden" to be "true".

**EDIT:**

The thing is that there are several variables (categories, such as music, sport, culture, job...) that will be true or false depending on whether the user enables them with toggle buttons or not. Then, there is information about several events, each of which is of a different category (e.g.: "Football match tomorrow" is a "sport" event, etc.). So, I want these events entries to disappear if the user disables its corresponding toggle button.

So, imagine there are 2 events of sport, 1 of music and 1 of job. When the toggle button for sport is disabled, I only want to see the 2 events of job and music, the sports ones should disappear.

To do so, I had thought of these variables with true or false, as I thought it would be easy to assign their value to the hidden attribute by default in Polymer. But it turns out it was not that easy. If you come with any other easy way to implement this, let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Whats wrong with a function? `isHidden: function { return tag === 'music' ? true : false }`

Comment: I may have explained myself wrong, but I don't think that function solves my problem. The thing is that the value of "sport" and "music" depends on other functions, so both those vars and the "tag" could be anything. Moreover, sport and music were just a couple of examples, but there are many other types of activity too.

Comment: Perhaps give more examples, also how do the *vars* fit into the picture? Your example shows *sport* as *false* but then you said the tag to *sport*.

Comment: I have eddited my post, so that there is a clearer example in case you have a better solution for my problem... TY!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question, but there are some ways to hide an element based on the value of a variable. If you are just starting with your Polymer project, check out version 0.9 (there has been a lot of changes).

Direct:

```
<div hidden?="{{tag == 'sports'}}">Hey I'm the sport category</div>
```

With code:

```
<div hidden?="{{hidden}}">Hey I'm the sport category</div>

Polymer({
  publish: {
    tag: "sport",
    hidden: xxxxxx
  },
  // The ready function gets called when the Polymer element is ready.
  ready:{
    if (this.tag == "xyz"){
      this.hidden = false;
      // Do other things..
    }
  }
});
```

In Polymer version >= 0.8 you can use computed properties:

```
<div hidden?="{{computeHidden()}}">Hey I'm the sport category</div>

Polymer({
  is: 'my-element',
  properties: {
      tag: String,
  },
  computeHidden: function() {
    if (this.tag == "xyz"){
      return false;
    }else{
      return true;
   }
 }
});
```

OR as a property declaration:

```
<div hidden?="{{hidden}}">Hey I'm the sport category</div>

Polymer({
    // define element prototype here
    is:'my-element',

    properties:{
        hidden:{
            type:Boolean,
            value:function() {
              if (this.tag == "xyz"){
                  return false;
              }else{
                  return true;
              }
            }
        }
    }
  });
```